# Linux kernel bug: [0.082336] [Firmware Bug]: CPU1: APIC id mismatch. Firmware: 1 APIC: 2

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux

I installed kali Linux in a VMware VM but I'm getting this error whenever I boot up:

> [0.082336] [Firmware Bug]: CPU1: APIC id mismatch. Firmware: 1 APIC: 2 
> [0.082336] [Firmware Bug]: CPU2: APIC id mismatch. Firmware: 2 APIC: 4 
> [0.082336] [Firmware Bug]: CPU3: APIC id mismatch. Firmware: 3 APIC: 6 
> [7.986536] atkbd serio0: failed to deactivate keyboard on isa0060/serio0

the VM works fine but using one processor only, which make the VM slow and produces a hotspot because one core is at full load all the time.

My processor architecture is intel 13th gen Raptor Lake.

feel free to reach out for any additional information.